# What (if any) javascript or php libraries are there for encryption that meet NIST requirements

Tags: encryption

We may need to encrypt some of the data in our software to meet healthcare privacy ("HIPAA") rules which simply defer to the [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/index.html) guild-lines. But it's really unclear what (if any) libraries for encryption meet NIST standards.

Are there any .js or php libararies approved by the NIST?

(And, yes, I've emailed them but I"m not holding my breath).

Comment: Since I can't know if your request for JS libraries is for server- or client-side use, a word of warning: If you're doing crypto in the browser, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Could you provide more information about what your attempting to protect (encrypt). Because if you are encrypting data that is entered in a browser form, that data is still available to other scripts (and sometimes other processes) in its original form.

If you are decrypting data returned from a server in the browser (aka: Ajax call) then that two is not secure.

Comment: The correct answer is that this should not be done in js or php. It should be done in the server (https)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NIST [provides a list of validated libraries.](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/1401val2013.htm)

OpenSSL is FIPS 140-2 validated, and both [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) and [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) provide OpenSSL bindings.

Obviously, you only have OpenSSL on the server.  [Don't do crypto in the browser.](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/)  Do transmit data between the browser and server over SSL and do necessary crypto on the server.

Comment: For those who may not be familiar with web security, josh is recommending using HTTPS. OpenSSL is one implementation of SSL (the protocol behind HTTPS) but it's not the only one. Using HTTPS is the only correct answer in this case and trying to do it manually in PHP or js is wrong.

Comment: Also, to meet NIST guidelines you should update your server and ssl software often. Otherwise you'll be vulnerable to old bugs and can potentially fail an audit. I know, I ran a HIPAA compliant website for 3 years.

Comment: @slebetman: Obviously, yes, you want to use HTTPS in transit.  However, once data is on the server and you want to encrypt it for *storage*, I'm saying you should use OpenSSL to accomplish that.

Comment: Ah. That's wrong. OpenSSL is for HTTPS. Encryption for storage has other solutions like encrypted partition etc. While you can do it yourself you really shouldn't be reinventing the wheel in matters like this. HIPAA does not require encrypted storage. Just encrypted transmission (what did you expect from a standard written by the industry it was supposed to regulate)

Comment: @slebetman, not at all.  OpenSSL -- despite its name -- is quite useful for things outside of SSL.  Even its homepage says "*The OpenSSL Project is a collaborative effort to develop [...] a full-strength general purpose cryptography library.*"  If you look at the PHP and Node APIs I linked in the answer, you'll notice that they allow you to use OpenSSL to encrypt arbitrary data with any of the cipher algorithms that OpenSSL supports -- nothing to do with SSL.  That said, you're right that the OP is probably better off not trying to roll his own (even with a proper crypto library).